# Is there an appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask questions about home appliances?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there an appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask questions about home appliances? Recommendations, safety concerns, operation and maintenance tips?

Answer (score 3):

[Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) would be suitable for some questions. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> We welcome these topics:
>   ...
>   Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances.

There is an [[appliances]](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appliances?mixed=1) tag, as well as more specific tags such as [[washing-machine]](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/washing-machine?mixed=1), which you can look through to see what kind of questions are on-topic.

Note that recommendations are specifically off-topic though. The same help page says:

> Note, the following are considered off-topic:
>   ...
>   Shopping assistance, product recommendations, or brand specific advice. (See the [discussion in meta](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions) for more details on this policy.)

Answer (score 2):

If it is an appliance involved in cooking or food preparation, [Seasoned Advice ("Cooking")](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/equipment/info) includes these in its *equipment* tag.

You won't get recommendations on what to buy or where to buy it, anywhere on Stack Exchange, and I can't find anywhere that deals with safety/operation/maintenance of general appliances.

Note that [Electronics & Electrical  Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) and [Home Improvement ("DIY")](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) have both made such questions off-topic.